# Use_frameworks versus Use_module_headers in pod file

Tags: ios, frameworks

To get my app to run using the new iOS 13.3.1 version, I had to alter my pod file.  Changed it by hashing out 'use_frameworks' and including ':modular_headers => true' on each pod line. (By the way changing to use_modular_headers at the top did not work).

My question: is there a drawback to using modular headers versus frameworks? Will this come back and bite me during the Apple approval?